# git push -u origin master command is not reflecting changes on github

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-push

I did 4 commits in my project till 3 commits I was able to see changes on GitHub but after 4rth commit it is not showing changes online.

git log --oneline

```
0d2084d (HEAD) fourth commit
a3fb0e9 (origin/master, master) third commit
89d2764 second commit
c600e93 first commit
```

git push -u origin master

```
Everything up-to-date
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
```

on GitHub:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the output of `git log --oneline`, we can see that the 4th commit is on a detached HEAD instead of `master`. `master` does have only 3 commits. This detached HEAD could most probably be caused by `git checkout a3fb0e9` or `git checkout origin/master`.

To apply the 4th commit onto `master`, you can

```
git checkout master
git merge 0d2084d
```

And then run `git push origin master` to push the 4th commit to the remote repository.